# How to implement a method when a property changes with CommunityToolkit?

Tags: c#, community-toolkit-mvvm

I would like to do something when a bool property changes the value when in the view the user chages the value.

I have  this:

```
[ObservableProperty]
bool _myProperty;

private void OnMyPropertyChanged()
{
    //DO SOMEHTING
}
```

In some documentation I have read that I could implement a method with MyProperty name, but the code is not execute.

The class in which this property is extends ObservableObject, so if I am not wrong the class implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

How I could I do something when the property value changes?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how it is done with CT but with [ReactiveUI](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/getting-started/compelling-example#create-viewmodels) it is an easy task (the assignment of `_searchResults` in the constructor is mindblowing)